# how do you request on a table with multi database

Tags: laravel

When i had one database i did :

```
$data=DB::table('data')->select(...)
```

How do I it with

```
$data=DB::connection('foo')->select(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it that way:

```
$data = DB::connection('foo')->table('data')->select(...);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can just configure your as many database you want in config/database.php file,

```
'custom_db1' => [
      'mysql' => [
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
      'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
      'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
      'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
      'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
      'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
      'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
      'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      'prefix' => '',
      'prefix_indexes' => true,
      'strict' => false,
      'engine' => null,
]
```

And Use it in eloquent Model like

```
protected $table = "custom_db1.table1";
```

Comment: yeah this would be the correct method.... and then you can create your own custom queries as per eg. @Adams query.